# Boss gave me unexpected money, then asks to work extra hours 30 days after my leave notice?

Tags: quitting, overtime, resignation, overworked

I start working in this software and hardware company 2 years ago as an Android developer. There were 4 developers in the team; 3 working on the server and me. Since the very beginning it was very easy to notice my skills were far above them so I start to make recommendations and helping them. After a few months my responsibility became working with the server, the database, writing REST APIs, developing the iOS app, Android app, write front-end website, etc..

Suddenly I have to do everything. So I mention to my boss my responsibilities were too much and I was afraid if one day I get sick, who will do my job? My boss told me not to worry.

So after 2 years I decided to quit, I gave 40 days notice to my boss and agreed he will find my replacement. After 30 days, there is no replacement and there is no evidence my boss is really looking for someone. This Monday my boss transferred to my bank account 2 times my salary and he sent me an email saying it's a way to say thanks for all my effort. Tuesday he asked my if I can work extra hours even above the legal working hours in a new project (that I estimate will take at least 40 days to do)..

Here is the problem: he just sent me that money because he wants me to work extra hours. How can I tell my boss that I will not work extra hours and after the my last day I will not do anymore work for this company?

Comment: You are on your notice period, simply *don't* work the extra hours either.

Comment: 40 days of notice for quitting is far too much, and you've learned the hard way exactly why.

Comment: @scatter  Its possible his employment contract required 40 days notice.  It seems its not uncommon to give a month notice for folks in Europe.

Comment: @scatter By law I am required to give 25 days. Because I know the kind of responsability I had so I decided by myself to give 40 days.

Comment: I feel like you should speak to accounting as to how this payment will be shown on your payslip (if it will be at all). Your employer might put it down as a bonus, and so it is less likely to be seen as an 'over-payment', which would make it safer to use.

Comment: I find it a bit weird that your boss just transfers money into your account, and that it doesn't go through a payroll system... what country is this? what about tax etc?

Comment: I would expect "salary", without any qualification, to refer to annual salary. Did you receive twice your annual salary?

Comment: "How can I tell my boss that I will not work extra hours and after the my last day I will not do anymore work for this company?" - It sounds like you should return the money.  *It sounds like your boss expects you to work those extra hours in return for the bonus.*  If you have fulfilled the requirements of notice period per your contract, you might consider just quitting.

Comment: @scatter In some country, like Italy, 40 days might be the minimum notice that can be given, depending on your seniority

Answer (score 25):

Firstly, don't spend the money! It's not yours; the company could turn around and say it was an "accounting mistake" and ask for it back.

Next set up a meeting with your boss and tell him what you said in your last sentence:

> I will not work extra hours and after the my last day I will not do anymore work for this company.

Just be calm and firm, he will try and persuade you to stay, just be polite and keep saying no. If you have a new job (good, I hope it better than the old one) or if you don't, just lie and say "I have found other employment and because of that along with other personal responsibilities I will not be working for you past this date" or something else along the lines of "no, I've got places to be and things to do".

If you are calm and consistent, the worse thing your boss can do is ask for the money back.

Comment: I would not recommend lying. It is non of your current bosses concern why you will stop working for the company after your last day. Any lie can backfire.

Comment: Do not do anything with that money until you see it on your final pay slip.

Comment: He sent me an email, saying "I sent you X quantity of money to say thanks for all your efforts."

Comment: @yaxarx great then there are litterally no downsides to telling him a more polite version of "I've got places to be and shit to do" but make sure to save that email somewhere on a personal machine or cloud account because he wouldn't be the first butthurt boss who deleted evidence to screw over one of their employees and he wouldn't be the last

Comment: The company could not recoup the money, they could ask for it back but the boss has already put in writing that the money is a thank you for work that has already been done so it legitimately belongs to the poster.

Comment: You are mistaken.  The money is the OP's, and they have written evidence of that.  The rest of the advice is good.

Comment: Print that email!

Comment: @PhilDin Are you a lawyer familiar with the laws where the OP is located? While your assertion may turn out to be true, if the company did try to take back that payment, you can be positive that lawyers would need to be involved to sort it out.

Comment: I would definitely speak to a lawyer ASAP about the money (and don't spend it in the meantime). Keep records of any information you have regarding it and show everything to the lawyer. If the employer put it in writing that the money is OP's with no strings attached as a bonus for prior work completed, then that seems pretty concrete, but don't risk it for the sake of a small legal consulting fee!

Answer (score 14):

> How can I tell my boss that I will not work extra hours and after the my last day I will not do anymore work for this company.

First thing you need to do is print out the email that your boss sent that explains that the extra money you received was a thank you for all your effort.  Make sure that you do not touch this money until at least a month after your last day and ask your HR/payroll department for a pay stub as documentation of receiving this money ( if you didn't already receive one).  Keep these two documents in a safe place.

Next, you need to be up front with your boss regarding the extra hours:

> Hey boss I would love to help out, but unfortunately my last day is X and I will not be able to dedicate any time outside of my standard hours for this new project.

Comment: If OP doubts the honesty of their employer, I'd forward the email with full headers to a different account to avoid any accusations of faking the printed version in MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the problem: he just sent me that money because he wants me to work extra hours.

Are you sure your boss sent you the money? Did you ever confirmed with him that he sent you money and in what amount?

> How can I tell my boss that I will not work extra hours and after the my last day I will not do anymore work for this company?

Tell your boss that you're willing to part as much knowledge as you can within the normal working hours up to when you quit.

It sounds like the condition of the bank deposit is that you continue to work for them. My advice is to quickly return the money (do not do this by withdrawing but instead writing a check or asking them to undo the deposit). You need to make it clear that you do not wish to work for them. Say no, and make sure you write an email like so,

> Dear Boss, you deposited $XXXX.YY into my bank account on the condition that I continue to work for you. I do not wish you work for you any longer and do not want this money. Please undo this. Thanks.

Get them to reply to that email and be sure to save that email. They may try something funny like say they never got the money back or that you took the money and never did the work you agreed to do. You need to make it clear and fast.